# What is happening under the hood of nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Consider this snippet of pseudo code:

```
i = 0;
while i < int.maxvalue {
  print(i)
  i += 1
}
```

While running this code in `nodejs` it started eating my RAM and crushed at the point of 2 GB, while on any other language with `garbage collector` that I tried(ruby, python, java) they ate ~3..~15 MB of RAM.

Just to understand what is happening behind the scene I want to ask - Why is it working like that in nodejs?

Update:
The real code on python:

```
import sys
i = 0
while i < sys.maxint:
  print(i)
  i += 1
```

and for node:

```
let i = 0;
while(i<Number.MAX_VALUE){
  console.log(i);
  i += 1;
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance Updated, maybe you use some flags while running this code? I'm running it inside Node REPL without flags.

Comment: Have you tried without printing?  Maybe the bottleneck is STDOUT and it's getting buffered.

Comment: Thanks, I see it too now. Yeah, it looks to be a console issue. Remove that, and memory stays constant

Comment: @CertainPerformance So what you're saying is that it's some sort of a bug with console class, not a global nodejs gc fault? Interesting. I wonder what is actually causing this issue tho.

Comment: @Brad coming to think logically I don't see any reasons why it should do so, but this might be true.

Comment: @AramHayrapetyan Why wouldn't it?  The process would have to block otherwise.  I don't think most folks want a process blocked on simple logging messages.  If you want more control over output flow, `process.stdout.write()` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Brad wait, why would it not block the process if it's getting buffered?

Comment: @AramHayrapetyan With the output getting buffered, the process can keep running while continuously just shoving data into the buffer.  It can keep doing its work without worrying about the state of the output.  Otherwise, the process has to stop and wait for the output to happen.